# Displaying Root Category in Magento Main Nav

Tags: magento-1.7, catalog, category

I was wondering if it was possible to have a custom block or a menu item that when hovered over displays a list of all the categories in the shop? I tried to do this with the Root Category but I can’t get the root category to show up in the main nav.

thanks

Answer (score 4):

It is not intended to show the Root Category and it is a lot of work to change this.

Just create a Category under the root and put all categories there in, then you habe a visible "root category".

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't sure if that would have any disadvantage the only thing I can think of is just having an extra link in the breadcrumbs, which is really no big deal at all. Thanks so much!

Comment: @fabian There are a couple of ways you can achieve this, and they don't require a lot of work. For some reason Magento doesn't want you to show the root category (also see `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Category::canShow`). Do you know of any side effects of showing it anyway?

Comment: Nope, never tried it and never thought about